# How to create the sequence and apply two tables in SQL Server using Entity framework 6 code first approach?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two table A and B

**Table A** - Id Primary key not identity

**Table B** - Id Primary key not identity  - Id Primary key not identity

How to create A and B Table primary key columns without identity(1,1) in entity framework 6 and apply sequence for these two table.

and this two tables need to implement sequence in SQL

if example Table A insert one record id is 1. and i will insert the Table B id is 2 like this

I was checked Identity off not working in script and Entity framework 6 
and also not able to create sequence In entity framework 6

But EFCore has sequencial feature

```
 modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("OrderNumbers", schema: "shared")
            .StartsAt(1000)
            .IncrementsBy(5);

        modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
            .Property(o => o.Id)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR shared.OrderNumbers");
```

In this

> HasSequence not available in Entity Framework 6

how to create sequence in EF 6 code first

Any one know please share

Comment: To rephrase the question, `Does EF 6 have something equivalent to EF Core's HasSequence`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Sequence in query in last Migration using following procedure

```
public override void Up()
{
Sql("CREATE SEQUENCE tbl_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;");
..........
..........
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Table_A",
            c => new
            {
                id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: false, defaultValueSql: 
               "NEXT VALUE FOR tbl_seq"),....
}

 CreateTable(
            "dbo.Table_B",
            c => new
            {
                id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: false, defaultValueSql: 
               "NEXT VALUE FOR tbl_seq"),....
}
```

Set in this place change the migration for create table of those tables set

**identity: false, 
 defaultValueSql: "NEXT VALUE FOR tbl_seq"**

after update the database. we check those table applied the sequence on those tables.